# Meaning in context: Trust vs believe

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I want to know when to use "***trust***" or "***believe***" in someone.

Thanks for your help.

PS: it's my first question on stack exchange, so please be kind. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you mean when you use each, or when to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Yeah, I mean when to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

*Trusting* someone can mean:

- you do not feel the need the verify what a person says, or
- you do not think a person will steal from you or work against your benefit.

*Believing* someone means you trust what they say (like the first definition above), but *believe* wouldn't ever mean the second definition of *trust* above.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So do you mean believe is a part of trust? I'm still little bit confused,Thanks anyway

Comment: Belief is trust in what someone or something says.  Trust can (not always) apply more to a person in general.